# Can a bundle be 3 transactions for security level 1?

Tags: transaction, security, bundles

[A bundle has 4 transactions](https://iota.readme.io/docs/bundles):

- The output; address and amount of IOTA recipient gets.
- The input; address, and amount of IOTA sender gives, and half of their signature.
- The other half of the sender's signature.
- Remaining ouput; if there is left over funds, you have to send it to your own address because IOTA address cannot be spent twice.

A transaction is **2673 trytes**, `signatureMessageFragment` (more info [here](https://iota.readme.io/v1.2.0/docs/the-anatomy-of-a-transaction)) has a size of **2187 trytes**, and an [IOTA signature's **length**](https://medium.com/@abmushi/iota-signature-and-validation-b95b3f9ec534#bcc4) = security * 2187 trytes.

If I am using security = 1, then my signature is exactly the size of `signatureMessageFragment`.

Does that mean I can tranfer IOTA in a bundle with only 3 transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

In case of security = 1 and you are spending *all* the funds on one address (with no change needed), you can even get away with only 2 transactions (one with the input and sig, and one with the output).